# Override z-index

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using darkmode.js https://darkmodejs.learn.uno/ library for darkmode. It uses css `mix-blend-mode` in order to bring Dark-mode. When I check manually it applies `transform : scale(1)` for dark mode.

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/darkmode-js@1.5.7/lib/darkmode-js.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function addDarkmodeWidget() {
        new Darkmode().showWidget();
      }
      window.addEventListener('load', addDarkmodeWidget);
    </script>
```

It does not work well with components of bootstrap (esp. widgets), hence I used it as per doc .

```
.darkmode-layer, .darkmode-toggle {
  z-index: 500;
}
```

Now I want to ignore CSS for some of the widgets like button (with class .btn-primary) when in dark mode. I want to show actual color of button in dark mode. I tried **darkmode-ignore** , **isolation: isolate**,  **mix-blend-mode: difference;** but it does not work.

Checkout jsfiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/27b06hy9/ I want to show background color of button (with class .btn-primary) as blue in dark mode. Remaining buttons can be shown as it is in dark mode.

Comment: Did you use `!important`?. Add some HTML too.

Comment: Yes tried but no success

Comment: I was going to advice !important too, but that was a shot in the dark. It would help if you created a full page showing your problem (using jsfiddle for example).

Comment: I just used some bootstrap 4 components and darkmodejs. It works as expected. You might not use your css + js links in correct order.

Comment: Thanks. I am using bootstrap 3. Would you mind sharing your jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t46up1nk/ on codepen you do not need to use the css you have shared. Use your css in correct order.

Comment: Thanks. It seems you misunderstood the issue. I just changed the class to btn-primary and it shows color in light orange when in darkmode. I want to make it blue. Hence I am trying to override CSS for button

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, you want something like this?
[image: Screensnip1]

Just add 'button' before your darkmode-toggle class in css

```
button .darkmode-layer, .darkmode-toggle {
  z-index: 500;
}
```

Also you can fiddle with power of

```
all:unset!important;
```

Comment: TIL about `all` in CSS.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to make it specific with .btn-primary class. I changed your code 'button' to '.btn-primary' it didn't work

Comment: "Sometimes it’s far easier to start from scratch with styling rather than fight against everything that is already there." -css-tricks

Comment: Gotcha. You don't have answer for this. Thanks!